# Convert Mat to **float

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have an OpenCV function which return type is Mat. 
How do I convert that to a 2 dimensional float array (** float)?

Probably very simple but I have not been able to do it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at [the documentation for the `Mat` class](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat) doesn't reveal any obvious 'convert to `float**`' operator, but you could probably do it by hand:

```
 Mat mat = (Mat_<float>(3,3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);

 // allocate and initialize a 2d float array
 float **m = new float*[mat.Rows];
 for (int r = 0; r < mat.Rows; ++r)
 {
    m[r] = new float[mat.Cols];
    for (int c = 0; c < mat.Cols; ++c)
    {
       m[r][c] = mat.at(r, c);
    }
 }

 // (use m for something)

 // don't forget to clean up!
 for (int r = 0; r < mat.Rows; ++r)
 {
    delete[] m[r];
 }
 delete[] m;
```

If you're not dead-set on using `float**`, you could use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) to avoid the awkward memory allocation/deallocation and reduce the potential for leaks.

You might also have some luck using `Mat::ptr<float>(n)` to get a `float*` to the `n`th row of a matrix, but if you don't copy the data out, I'm not sure what guarantees you'll have about how long that pointer will remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this,

```
float a[M][N]; //M and N are compile-time constants!
float **p = a; //error
```

then you cannot do that.

However, you can do this:

```
float (*p)[N] = a; //ok
```

But if that doesn't help you and you want `float**` at any cost, then use two `for` loops, and do that manually, copying each element from `a` to `p`: