# convert a Mat type to an array of float pointer

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new in opencv and c++. I need to know how to convert a Mat format to an array of float pointer in opencv.

Is there any function available in opencv to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'array of float pointer' sounds a bit absurd. can you give some more context ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: By "Mat format" do you mean a Matlab *.mat file type?

Comment: As this question is tagged with opencv, i guess cv::Mat is meant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Mat to \*\*float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793723/convert-mat-to-float)

Comment: yes, i meant Mat format in opencv and I want to copy it into an array which is contained of pointer to float.

Comment: I am wondering if there is any function in opencv that do it in a simple way or not.